# How to restore local wordpress server from cash?

Tags: wordpress

I'm fairly new to development and have been trying to create my own wordpress theme. While editing the theme today I made a mistake in the code and now the wordpress page won't load at all. It's just a white page and I can't even access wp-admin. I have wordpress installed locally with Bitnami.

I've researched how to fix this wordpress crashing problem and everyone keeps saying with FTP. But with a local server, from as far as I can tell, I don't think that works. I'm using Cyberduck and have tried to enter the IP address of the local server wordpress site to access the files but Cyberduck doesn't pull anything up. I have also tried stopping the server and starting it again and this doesn't help.

How do I recover my wordpress site from a crash when it's stored on a local (Bitnami) server?

Comment: Step 1 would be to turn on WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php and try to find out what the error is exactly. If you're able to edit the theme locally just browse up a few directories until you're in the site root. FTP isn't used when working locally.

Comment: Can you access your files through your control panel on your host?